# What is the difference between `npm i` and `CI=false npm i`?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have my continuous integration pipeline broken after a particular commit.

I can't do `npm i` nor `npm ci` anymore, `yarn` work fine.

I am using node v13.11.0 and npm 6.14.2

I expect the command to pass in both CI and local env.

Instead, it fails during CI with :

```
npm ERR! cb() never called! when doing npm install
```

This is the full log:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kopax/3b627be39a50cf0a6bea6f20f7d179b2/raw/7448fb398a713e76620f138f7e7337eadb88f052/npm-error.log

However, when I set `CI=false`, the CI pass, why and what are the differences?